# Sending a message to deallocated object is working

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, memory-management

The simplest code ever in Objective-C causes weird behavior:

```
#import Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    NSObject *obj = [[NSObject alloc] init];
    NSLog(@"retain count %d",[obj retainCount]);//print 1
    [obj release];//obj deallocated
    NSLog(@"retain count %d",[obj retainCount]); //still printing 1 in Snow Leopard! Why??


    [pool drain];
    return 0;
}
```

The second `NSLog()` should print "message retainCount sent to freed object=0x103eb0".
If you use Leopard everything works fine, but in Snow Leopard the second NSLog still prints `1`.

Is this a bug in the Snow Leopard version of Xcode?

Answer (score 6):

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1529081/code-example-why-can-i-still-access-this-nsstring-object-after-ive-released-it/1529089) question.

It's not a bug. Once you release an object with a retain count of one, the objc runtime simply calls `dealloc` and does not bother decreasing the retain count. That's how it's always worked. Also, just because an object has been sent `dealloc` doesn't mean its data on the heap is immediately destroyed. It's just marked for destruction later.

Comment: The memory is not so much "marked for destruction" as "available for reuse by something else".  But nothing explicitly overwrites the freed memory right when its freed.

Answer (score 2):

Sending a message to a deallocated instance is *undefined behavior*. You are not supposed to do it. It could work; it could not. Because you are not supposed to do it, they do not have to make it so that the result is consistent with your expectations.

Answer (score 1):

Setting `NSZombieEnabled` to `YES` in the environment variables of your application will allow Foundation to detect this programming error, and report it as a console message which is helpful for debugging.