# Memory Management in Objective C regarding reference count

Tags: objective-c, memory-management

NOT USING ARC OR AUTOMATIC GARBAGE COLLECTION

```
     -(Fraction*) add: (Fraction*) f
        {
            Fraction *result = [[Fraction alloc] init];
            //To do

            return result;
        }

    //after the function returns. What will the reference count 
of object that result was pointing to. See main.m below.
```

IN main.m

```
    int main(int argc, char* argv[])
    {
        //To do

        Fraction *ans = [[Fraction alloc] init];



        ans = [f1 add: f2]; 
        //I guess that the refrence count of the object that ans will be pointing 
after this statement will be 1 or 2.
        //...

    }
```

//An extract regarding this from stephen kochan objective-c

When using manual memory management, this method presents a problem. The result object is alloc’ed and returned from the method after the calculations have been performed. Because the method has to return that object, it can’t release it—that would cause it be destroyed right then and there. Probably the best way to resolve this issue is to autorelease the object so that its value can be returned, with its release delayed until the autorelease pool is drained. You can take advantage of the fact that the autorelease method returns its receiver and embeds it in expressions like this:

```
Fraction *result = [[[Fraction alloc] init] autorelease]; 
//or like this: 
return [result autorelease];
```

Note : According to extract it seems that refrence count will be 2. If it's so please explain why ?

Comment: There a many, many similar question on memory management in Objective C. See [Memory management in Objective-C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020103/memory-management-in-objective-c) as an example.

Answer (score 0):

//THE ANSWER ASSUMES NO ARC AND AUTOMATIC GARBAGE COLLECTION

In add function :
An instant of fraction class is created and the reference to it is stored in `result`. Since, `alloc and init` are used for creating that instant `result` becomes it's owner. And only an owner must release the object it owns when it's use is completed.But, the `result` doesn't release it `(See add)`. Now add returns the reference to the object which was owned by `result` and it is stored in `ans` in `main.m` . Since, ans is not the owner of the object it has reference to and hasn't made any attempt to acquire, so the reference count of the object will be 1. Since, the the owner of this object can't be referenced any longer so, we can't release it. (Blah! a memory leak). 

But what if we do `[ans release]`. Though it is bad practice. Can it save memory leak... 
I think yes. Please comment if it won't

Comment: @CarlVeazey I was hoping this kind of answer. Please correct me if I am wrong.